# Check GCC version in runtime

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I need to find out the available (installed in the system) GCC version (Major and minor) inside the execution of a c program (in runtime). Meaning, programatically extract the version of the available gcc (same as if I was in a shell and typed gcc --version, but in a c program).

The `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` are only useful in compile time and I've found the `gnu_get_libc_version()` function from `gnu/libc_version.h`, but it only gets me the libc version and I need the GCC version. If there is something similar for GCC it would be great...

I would really like to avoid calling a shell command to do this.

Comment: Do you want the version of the compiler *that's installed on the system*, or the compiler that was used to compile your program?

Comment: I think i wants the compiler that compiled the executable ...

Comment: but then he already has the answer...

Comment: Why do you ask? At runtime you don't even any `gcc` compiler!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Invoke the `gcc` shell command with the parameter `--version`; it's the correct way to do this. See `popen()` to do that.

Or you can invoke GCC with to compile a program which prints the values for `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__`. But that will not work if the GCC in question is configured for cross compilaton.

Alternatives would be to search the binary for version strings and hoping that you get the right one, that the format doesn't change and that the version string is distinct enough for you to recognize it with enough confidence.

In 1.5 words: Don't.

Comment: "it's the correct way to do this". No. There is *no* correct way to do this, because the question is based on apparently bogus assumptions.

Answer (score 19):

There is a simple way:

```
$ gcc -dumpversion
4.6
```

Comment: There is also `-dumpfullversion` which dumps (surprisingly) full GCC version.

Answer (score 5):

> I need to find out the available (installed in the system) GCC version (Major and minor)

What are you going to do with the information?

You can't get a *meaningful* answer to your question, because

1. The user may not have any GCC installed in `/usr/bin`
2. May have 5 *different* versions installed elsewhere on the system
3. May have a version in `/usr/bin` which *pretentds* to be `gcc-X.Y`, but is actually `gcc-Z.W`, or `Clang`, or `icc`, etc.

But if you insist on getting a meaningless answer, `popen("gcc --version")` and parse the resulting output.

Comment: -1 Maybe he has a list which GCCs are installed; the question is specifically: "How do I figure out which versions a GCC has" not "How do I find all the different installed GCCs".

Comment: Why does the `popen` version give a *meaningless answer*?