# Reading libstdc++ version at runtime

Tags: c++, libstdc++

My application is affected by [a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81395) in older versions of *libstdc++* in a rather serious data-lossy way. The remedies of how to select the right library version with `-rpath` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are known, but not reliable to changes in deployment and build. After being bitten more than once myself I would like to stop the suffering and introduce a runtime-check for a sufficiently new version of *libstdc++*. How can I access the version in order to print a big fat warning message in case of the deployment failing to use the right version. Note that I need the *minor* version `libstdc++.so.6.0.25` a.k.a. `GLIBCXX_3.4.25` that comes with gcc 8.

Comment: might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516041/check-gcc-version-in-runtime

Comment: you can define the some variable with result from `g++ -dumpversion`, and then check for it in code.

Comment: Unfortunately the gcc version doesn't help. In fact we usually build with a non-default gcc 8.2, but that simply links `libstdc++.so.6` - which also happens to be satisfied by the system `libstdc++.so.6.0.22` coming from system gcc 6.3.0.

Comment: You can check which library is being used by `gcc -lstdc++` and later check it by `strings` command + `grep GLIBCXX`, and find the `GLIBCXX_3.4.25` from it.

Comment: @BladeMight That's not a runtime check that the program itself can perform in any easy way.

Comment: On Linux you can check contents of `/proc/self/maps` from the running process for incorrect libraries. Not trivial but not very hard.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354636/how-do-you-find-what-version-of-libstdc-library-is-installed-on-your-linux-mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a linux program that simply lists the absolute real paths of the DSOs it has
loaded (as enumerated by [dl_iterate_phdr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr)) that are accessible files.
(All linux programs load [`linux-vdso.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html), which isn't actually a file).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <link.h>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int
get_next_SO_path(dl_phdr_info *info, size_t, void *p_SO_list)
{
    auto & SO_list =
        *static_cast<std::vector<std::string> *>(p_SO_list);
    auto p_SO_path = realpath(info->dlpi_name,NULL);
    if (p_SO_path) {
        SO_list.emplace_back(p_SO_path);
        free(p_SO_path);
    }
    return 0;
}

std::vector<std::string>
get_SO_realpaths()
{
    std::vector<std::string> SO_paths;
    dl_iterate_phdr(get_next_SO_path, &SO_paths);
    return SO_paths;
}


int main()
{
    auto SO_paths = get_SO_realpaths();
    for (auto const & SO_path : SO_paths) {
        std::cout << SO_path << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which for me runs like:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp && ./a.out
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
```

[Live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d09662993d99b87e)

As you see, the full version appears. With a bit of filename parsing, you
can take it from there. Getting the whole DSO list, as per `get_SO_realpaths`,
before looking for any `libstdc++` would let you detect, if you want, the freak possibility
of more than one `libstdc++` being loaded.

Comment: I admit this is a more complex solution than I had hoped for, but fairly elegant never the less.